# where should i encode this html data in an asp.net mvc site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-encode

here is my view code:

```
<%=Model.HtmlData %>
```

here is my controller code:

```
    public ActionResult GetPage()
    {
        ContentPageViewModel vm = new ContentPageViewModel();
        vm.HtmlData = _htmlPageRepository.Get("key");
        return View(vm);
    }
```

my repository class basically queries a database table that has the fields:

```
id, pageName, htmlContent
```

the .Get() method passes in a pageName (or key) and returns the htmlContent value.

Right now i have just started this (haven't persisted anything to the db yet) so i am not doing any explicit encoding in my code now.

What is the best practice for where i need to do encoding (in the model, the controller, the view ??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encoding is a concern of the view. You may have two very different displays using the same database, so often it isn't advisable to store the data in a state required by the specific view.

As a side note... If you are using .NET 4

```
<%: Model.HtmlData %>
```

Is the new

```
<%= Sever.HtmlEncode(Model.HtmlData) %>
```

Comment: Good answer, although I would also mention `HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode()` in case you're sticking data in an attribute.

Comment: i am editing and saving it to the db. so are you saying save directly without do any encoding on the persistence ??

Comment: Quick story - I worked somewhere where they encoded everything on the way in to the database to save processing (you encode it once on the way in - job done). The data was displayed on a website and all was well. They then added a new UI on top of the data, running within a kiosk - and it wasn't web based - so they ended up having to un-encode everything on the fly each time they wanted to display the data. If the UI requires a specific encode / fiddle, it should be responsible for doing it. The data shouldn't be polluted by this requirement. Hope this helps.