# how to save html to a database field

Tags: html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

i have an [tiny editor](http://www.leigeber.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/) web page where my users can use this editor and i am saving the html into my database.

i am having issues saving this html to my database. for example if there is a name with a "'" or if there are other html character "<,",">" etc, my code seems to blow up on the insert.

Is there any best practices about taking any arbitrary html and have it persist fully to a db field without worrying about any specific characters.

Comment: The ability to embed Javascript is a rather large concern.

Comment: I just realized that tiny editor seems to do this for you so thats why i was confused why everything was working without me doing anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm wondering if you are building the full query.  Instead use a parameterized query and that should eliminate your data problems.

```
string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO table (name, information, other) VALUES (@name, @information, @other)";

SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, db.Connection);
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@name", info);
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@information", info1);
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@other", info2);
cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

do you insert using `SqlParameter`? If yes, you should not have problems, check that.

Comment: In principle yes, but in-case any any other parts of the SQL either execs or make assumptions about contents of the database, you should always encode user input.

Answer (score 0):

You could just HtmlEncode the data.
You'll have a HttpContext.Current.Server object, so in pseudo code you'd just do:

```
Database.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(myHtml));
```

and to retrieve it:

```
myHtml = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(DataBase.Load());
```

Comment: this seems to go against this best practice off doing encoding in the view -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914062/where-should-i-encode-this-html-data-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site

Comment: I just realized that tiny editor seems to do this for you so thats why i was confused why everything was working without me doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Just reading through this - is your problem actually on the insert statement or do you get a problem from the web server before it ever hits your controller? Noticing that you tagged the question with asp.net-mvc, you may need to make sure that you have decorated your controller method with the [ValidateInput(false)] attribute.

Comment: ... and I agree with OMG Ponies, et al., that you *really* need to make sure that you have a need to accept HTML into your db.